# Check if row has n minutes less or more than previous one

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, time, row

I have this dataset *df* (it has more than 100,000 rows)

| sensor_id | date | time | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 225 | 2022/04/01 | 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 225 | 22/04/01 | 00:10:00 | 35 |
| 225 | 22/04/01 | 00:10:00 | 35 |
| 225 | 22/04/01 | 00:20:00 | 31 |
| 225 | 22/04/01 | 00:30:00 | 33 |
| 225 | 22/04/01 | 00:40:00 | 32 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 225 | 22/05/01 | 26:50:00 | 40 |

I would like to check if each time in row is equal to the previous one +10 minutes. I'd like to print like a series of  `TRUE/FALSE`
so I can make tables and statistics. Alternatively, I would like at least to print a new column to display the time difference (in minutes) between one row and the previous one.

(Obviously, the formula should keep in mind the fact that if time is, for example, 16:58, next row should be 15:08 and still be `TRUE`)
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this might help you:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~sensor_id,        ~date,      ~time, ~measurement,
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:00:00",         "34",
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:10:00",         "35",
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:10:00",         "35",
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:20:00",         "31",
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:30:00",         "33",
       "225",   "22/04/01", "00:40:00",         "32",
       "225",   "22/05/01", "26:50:00",         "40"
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    time = lubridate::hms(time),
    is_equal = (time == lag(time)),
    diff_minutes = as.numeric(lubridate::as.difftime(time - lag(time))/60)
  )

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  sensor_id date     time       measurement is_equal diff_minutes
  <chr>     <chr>    <Period>   <chr>       <lgl>           <dbl>
1 225       22/04/01 0S         34          NA                 NA
2 225       22/04/01 10M 0S     35          FALSE              10
3 225       22/04/01 10M 0S     35          TRUE                0
4 225       22/04/01 20M 0S     31          FALSE              10
5 225       22/04/01 30M 0S     33          FALSE              10
6 225       22/04/01 40M 0S     32          FALSE              10
7 225       22/05/01 26H 50M 0S 40          FALSE            1570
```

Comment: @Vinicíous Fèlix Unfortunately your code gives this error:                                                              
`Error in mutate(., time = lubridate::hms(time), is_equal = if_else(time == : 

Caused by error in `as.character()`:
! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: Do you have `dplyr` and `lubridate` installed?

Comment: This: `if_else(time == lag(time), TRUE, FALSE)` is just `time == lag(time)`. No need for ifelse and to assign boolean. The result of `==` is boolean

Comment: @Vinicius Felix, I have them installed, but it still doesn't work. The resulting table is filled with NAs